# Printing two images in one

Tags: java, image, rgb

I'm new to Java and I have a problem with this code. 
The first part works perfectly, it gets the RGB values of every pixel of an input image, then it multiplies the values by specific number and saves the result as new image.

```
try {
    File input = new File("obr4.png");
    image2 = ImageIO.read(input);
    int width = image2.getWidth();
    int height = image2.getHeight();
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            Color c = new Color(image2.getRGB(j, i));

            int red = (int) (c.getRed() * Math.abs(text2value));
            if (red > 255) {
                red = 255;
            }
            int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * Math.abs(text2value));
            if (green > 255) {
                green = 255;
            }
            int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * Math.abs(text2value));
            if (blue > 255) {
                blue = 255;
            }

            Color newColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
            image2.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
            //System.out.println("Row: "+i+" Column: "+j+" Red: "+red+" Green: "+green+" Blue: "+blue);
        }
    }
    File output2 = new File("grayscale2.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(image2, "jpg", output2);
    repaint();

} catch (Exception e2) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Same code with different values also works for second image.

Now the tricky part: I want the two new created images put in just one picture - just get all pixel values form `pic1` and  `pic2`, add them together and print the result.
So far I have this code:

```
try {
    File input1 = new File("grayscale1.jpg");
    File input2 = new File("grayscale2.jpg");

    finalImage1 = ImageIO.read(input1);
    finalImage2 = ImageIO.read(input2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
            Color c = new Color(finalImage1.getRGB(j, i));
            int red1 = (int) (c.getRed());
            int green1 = (int) (c.getGreen());
            int blue1 = (int) (c.getBlue());

            Color o = new Color(finalImage2.getRGB(j, i));
            int red2 = (int) (o.getRed());
            int green2 = (int) (o.getGreen());
            int blue2 = (int) (o.getBlue());

            int red = (red1 + red2) / 2;
            if (red > 255) {
                red = 255;
            }
            int green = (green1 + green2) / 2;
            if (green > 255) {
                green = 255;
            }
            int blue = (blue1 + blue2) / 2;
            if (blue > 255) {
                blue = 255;
            }

            Color newColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
            finalImage.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
            //  System.out.println("Row: "+i+" Column: "+j+" Red: "+red+" Green: "+green+" Blue: "+blue);
        }
    }
    File output = new File("finalImage.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(finalImage, "jpg", output);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Sum error");
}
```

It should work same as the previous codes, but it doesn't. Always gives "Sum error". The problem seems to be somewhere in creating the `finalImage`, because if I print the values into console it seems to by all right.
Please, if you have any idea, what is wrong, let me know. Thank you

Comment: do e.printStackTrace() to know which line throws exception

Comment: And where did you initialize finalImage?

Comment: Meraman: apparently the error is in this lane: finalImage.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB()); I initialized the finalImage at the beginning of the code as BufferedImage, same as  image2, finalImage1 and finalImage2.

Comment: And what type of exception.

Comment: This is what it says: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at package.Class.<init>(Applet.java:177)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: That means finalImage is null, and it has not been initialized. Try to check if it is initialized? Try to check if it is null before invoking method "setRGB()" on it.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand what you just suggested. But it is initialized at the beginning, and by System.out.println(finalImage); I can see, it is null before setting "setRGB()".

Comment: Without full code, sorry I can't help.

Comment: I think i just fixed it, the problem was that the finalImage was not really initialized, you were right. I just add a a new line: finalImage = ImageIO.read(input1); before the "for" loop. Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much.